# Vm virtualbox ubuntu, cant run .c file from terminal

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, virtual-machine

I have the file example_action.c in example folder.

In terminal I enter

cd example

ls

and it shows example_action.c example.file

I am then trying to run the example_action.c over example.file and output the result.

./example_action example.file result.file

but every variation I try gives a different error.

bash:example_action not found

command not recognised

and so on.

Do I need to install something to make this work?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

To run a c program file, first compile it using gcc. U should have the gcc installed in your virtual machine. Then compile it by typing "gcc filename.c" in a terminal opened in that folder. It will generate a "a.out" file. Then run the c file by typing "./a.out". 
And also you should add the file extension ".c" with your file name every time.

```
bash:example_action not found
```

This error is because the filename is example_action.c

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to run a C source code file (extension `.c`). You will need to translate the file into machine language first (speak: compiling), like so:

```
gcc -o example_action example_action.c
```

(*`-o` to specify the name of the output file, otherwise gcc will use `a.out` by default*)

Then you can use the produced executable:

```
./example_action example.file result.file
```